# Making a POST request to my Logic App but my App doesn't show it's been triggered

Tags: azure, http, azure-logic-apps

I make a post request to this logic app

[image]
[image]

and it returns
[image]

But my logic app never shows that it's been triggered

[image]

The next step after "When a HTTP request is received" is a GET method that I'm trying to see what it returns, and I figured I'd see that info in the trigger history or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve defined it as `Stateless` and `Stateless` flows don’t log any results.  Your flow needs to be `Stateful`.

`Stateless` workflows perform near on 10 times better (depending on the amount of work it’s doing) but you only want to use them if you’re not concerned about logging.

This links is great because it also leads to the official documentation.

https://github.com/Azure/LogicAppsUX/issues/3705